# Обрыв соединения при запросе на добавление в Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, heroku

При отправлении формы получаю такую ошибку, при этом если я жму кнопку назад и отправляю форму повторно, то запрос срабатывает и добавление происходит, такая ошибка появляется только при работе с одним из трех классов, остальные работают нормально. Работа ведётся в базой данных расположенной на Heroku.

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:397)
    at com.dao.episode.EpisodeDAOImpl.addEpisode(EpisodeDAOImpl.java:51)
    at com.dao.episode.EpisodeServiceImpl.addEpisode(EpisodeServiceImpl.java:16)
    at com.bascon.HelloController.addEpisodeAction(HelloController.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 90 830 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 14 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3552)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3452)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3893)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4842)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.poll(PooledConnections.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3004)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462)
    ... 58 more
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="session">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ac8c4d10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net/heroku_7975f769758d9fa?reconnect=true?UseUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bf529a773566a9</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
  <mapping class="com.model.Comment"/>
  <mapping class="com.model.Image"/>
  <mapping class="com.model.Episode"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

EpisodeDAOimpl.java (Ошибочная)

```
package com.dao.episode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.model.Comment;
import com.model.Episode;

public class EpisodeDAOImpl implements EpisodesDAO {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Episode.class).buildSessionFactory();

    public List<Episode> getAllEpisodes(int page) {

        int first = 0;

        for (int i=1;i<page;i++) {
            first = first + 10;
        }

        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Episode> eps = new ArrayList<Episode>();
        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            Query query = sess.createQuery("FROM Episode");
            query.setFirstResult(first);
            query.setMaxResults(10);
            eps = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }
        return eps;
    }

    public void addEpisode(Episode episode) {
        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            sess.save(episode);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }

    }

    public void deleteEpisode(int id) {
        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            Episode com = sess.load(Episode.class, id);
            if (null != com) {
                sess.delete(com);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }
    }

    public Episode getEpisode(int id) {

        Episode eps = null;
        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            eps = sess.load(Episode.class, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }

        return eps;
    }

    public long getCount() {        
        Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        long i = 0;
        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            i = (Long) sess.createQuery("select count(*) from Episode").uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }
        return i;
    }

}
```

Episode.java (Модель)

```
package com.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "episodes_table")
public class Episode {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "episode_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "episode_title")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "episode_link")
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "episode_desc")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 300)
    private String desc;

    @Column(name = "upload_data")
    private Date date;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Episode(String title, String link,String desc, Date date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Episode() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }



}
```

HelloController.java (Контроллер)

```
package com.bascon;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.jboss.logging.Param;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.dao.comment.CommentService;
import com.dao.comment.CommentServiceImpl;
import com.dao.episode.EpisodeServiceImpl;
import com.dao.image.ImageServiceImpl;
import com.model.Comment;
import com.model.Episode;
import com.model.Image;
import com.validation.EpisodeValidation;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    @Autowired
    EpisodeValidation epsiodeValidator;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    //Три сервиса для работы с базой данных
    CommentServiceImpl commentService = new CommentServiceImpl();
    EpisodeServiceImpl episodeService = new EpisodeServiceImpl();
    ImageServiceImpl imageService = new ImageServiceImpl();

    //Приветственная страница
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView Welcome(){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("Hello");

        String rick = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/AqT-MJnbePM";      
        String title = "Добро пожаловать на мой сайт о Madness Combat";
        md.addObject("title", title);
        md.addObject("rick",rick);

        return md;
    }

    //Игра в Project Nexus
    @RequestMapping(value = "/playNexus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView PlayNexus(){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("Nexus");

        Comment come = new Comment();

        String title = "Здесь вы можеть сыграть в Madness Project Nexus";
        String link = "http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/592473";

        md.addObject("title", title);
        md.addObject("link",link);

        return md;
    }

    //Форма с добавлением эпизодов
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addEpisode", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView AddEpisode(){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("AddEpisode");
        String title = "Добавить новый эпизод";
        String but = "Загрузить";


        String titlePlac = "Напишите название файла здесь";
        String linkPlac = "Ссылка должна содержать https://www.youtube.com/embed/";
        String descPlac = "Введите описание здесь";

        Episode episode = new Episode();

        md.addObject("episode",episode);
        md.addObject("title",title);
        md.addObject("titlePlac", titlePlac);
        md.addObject("linkPlac", linkPlac);
        md.addObject("descPlac", descPlac);
        md.addObject("butto",but);

        return md;
    }

    //Метод POST, добавляющий эпизод
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addEpisodeAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEpisodeAction(@Validated @ModelAttribute("episode") Episode episode, BindingResult result ,ModelMap map) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        map.addAttribute("title", episode.getTitle());
        map.addAttribute("link",episode.getLink());
        map.addAttribute("desc",episode.getDesc());

        /*epsiodeValidator.validate(episode, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "redirect:/addEpisode";
        } else {}*/

            String mel = new String(episode.getTitle().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            String mec = new String(episode.getLink().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            String mev = new String(episode.getDesc().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

            episode.setTitle(mel);
            episode.setLink(mec);
            episode.setDesc(mev);

        episodeService.addEpisode(episode);

        return "redirect:/getSeries/1";

    }

    //Список эпизодов
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getSeries/{id}")
    public ModelAndView GetSeries(@PathVariable int id){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("AllEpisodes");
        String title = "Вы можеть смотреть сериал Madness Combat здесь";

        long count = episodeService.getCount();

        long pages = count / 10 + 1;

        List<Episode> eps = episodeService.listEpisode(id);

        for (Episode ep : eps) {
            System.out.println(ep.getTitle());
        }

        System.out.println("https://www.youtube.com/embed/DrtlTO5eD0U".length() );

        md.addObject("pages",pages);
        md.addObject("episodes",eps);
        md.addObject("title",title);

        return md;
    }

    //Просмотр эпизодов
    @RequestMapping(path = "/watchEpisode/{id}")
    public ModelAndView watchEpisode(@PathVariable int id){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("WatchEpisode");

        Episode eps = episodeService.getEpisode(id);
        String title = eps.getTitle();

        md.addObject("title",title);
        md.addObject("episode",eps);

        return md;
    }

    //Метод POST добавления комметариев
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addComment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addComment(@Validated @ModelAttribute("comment") Comment comment, BindingResult result, ModelMap model ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        model.addAttribute("author", comment.getAuthor());
        model.addAttribute("content", comment.getContent());

        String mel = new String(comment.getAuthor().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        String mec = new String(comment.getContent().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        comment.setAuthor(mel); 
        comment.setContent(mec);

        commentService.addComment(comment);

        return "redirect:/comments/1";
    }

    //Список комметариев
    @RequestMapping(value = "/comments/{id}")
    public ModelAndView Commentaries(@PathVariable int id){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("Comments");
        String title = "Оставьте отзыв";        
        String post = "Отправить";

        long count = commentService.getCount();
        long pages = count / 5 + 1;

        List<Comment> coms = commentService.listComments(id);

        Comment comment = new Comment();        

        md.addObject("comment", comment);       
        md.addObject("comments",coms);
        md.addObject("title",title);
        md.addObject("Post",post);
        md.addObject("pages", pages);       

        return md;
    }

    //Доступ к галерее (В разработке)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/galery/{id}")
    public ModelAndView Gallery(@PathVariable int id){
        ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView("Gallery");

        Image image = new Image();

        long count = commentService.getCount();
        long pages = count / 20 + 1;

        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

        images = imageService.getGallery(id);

        String title2 = "Посмотрите галерею";
        String butto = "Загрузить картинку";


        md.addObject("butto", butto);
        md.addObject("title2",title2);
        md.addObject("image",image);
        md.addObject("images",images);
        md.addObject("pages",pages);

        return md;
    }

    //Добавление изображений (В разработке)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addImage(@Validated @ModelAttribute("image") Image image, ModelMap map, BindingResult result ) throws IOException{

        map.addAttribute("title", image.getTitle());
        map.addAttribute("file", image.getFile());

        String mel = new String(image.getTitle().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

        image.setTitle(mel);

        imageService.addImage(image);
        return "redirect:/galery/1";
    }
}
```

UPD: Соединение падает через определенный промежуток времени, примерно 5 минут

UPD2: Я ошибся, проблемы соединения есть со всеми таблицами.

Comment: если запустить локально, то появляется ли ошибка?

Comment: Нет, данная ошибка появляется только при работе с БД расположенной на Heroku, она является полной копией той, что работает на локалке, и проблема происходит только с одной из таблиц, остальные две работают прекрасно. 
На heroku используется плагин ClearDB MySQL

Comment: Не пробовали в техподдержку Heroku обращаться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После недели проб и ошибок проблема была решена путем добавления и тонкой настройки библиотеки c3p0, поначалу всё тормозило и вылетал Request Timeout, но в итоге всё прекрасно заработало, выкладываю конфиг Hibernate, может кому пригодится в подобном случае.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="session">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">3</property> 
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bf529a773566a9</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ac8c4d10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net:3306/heroku_7975f769758d9fa?reconnect=true?UseUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
  <mapping class="com.model.Comment"/>
  <mapping class="com.model.Image"/>
  <mapping class="com.model.Episode"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```